# Rejecting messages if request limit is hit

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

I am new to camel and trying to achieve something like below:

I need to process 5 parallel messages, for the 6th message Throttler should reject the message and throw some exception. In higher versions I can see rejectExecution is there to handle this scenario. Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same with camel 2.2.0 version

```
from("seda:a")
  .throttle(100).rejectExecution(true)
  .to("seda:b");
```

But this works for higher version, looking for something similar in camel 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

If the feature is added in a higher version, then you cannot do this in the older version. Camel 2.x is also EOL.

You can write your own throttler as a Java processor/bean and use that instead .